# Follow Active Quads gives me disorted, streched UV

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a track mesh. But when I use "Follow Active Quads", generated UV has weird stretch.

[image]

Result texture also getting messed.

[image]

Every faces are connected and all of them are quads, no duplicated vertices.

Using Pack UV doesn't helped as well. What am I missing?

Here's the File link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kbwjgpCO1xxRivDN4FYtssKej4NjlmXT

Comment: Follow Active Quads relies on UV coordinates for the selected and active quad.

Answer (score 1):

If you unwrap again (<kbd>U</kbd>) but choose *Reset*, then again <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads*, it seems to work fine. You must have unwrap wrongly at a moment, and as you didn't reset it kept it wrong (don't know why we have to reset though).